# Function used before it was defined error

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress theme with Roots/Sage, and I have a small custom js file with a couple of functions for using a back to top button in pages.
When running gulp to build the assets for dist, I get a jshint error (well 2 actually) as below

```
  line 1  col 49  Missing semicolon.
  line 2  col 13  'scrollFunction' was used before it was defined.
```

The file I used is below.

```
 window.onscroll = function(){scrollFunction()};
   function scrollFunction(){
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 1000 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1000) {
            document.querySelector("#topBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.querySelector("#topBtn").style.display = "none";
        }



    }
  function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

   }
```

It does work fine in test htmlpages although I havent yet tried it in Wordpress.
Searching this site seems to throw up a variety of answers for this ranging from disable jshint errors to fix your code, so I am just wondering what is the best way to do this.

Additionally, when the file is built for dist the window.onscroll top line is removed leaving just the 2 functions. Also I cant find the missing semi-colon on line one it's not obvious to me.

Tips welcome, Thanks

Comment: The missing semi-colon is after `scrollFunction()` on line 1, not after the }

Comment: Also, don't disable jshint, as a recent linter plugin, it makes for beautiful code. Move line 1 to after the function definition

Comment: That's fixed it Thanks.